# Find out Pivot, Resistance and Support Levels for 30m Timeframe

Tags: pine-script

the following snippet of code I use to find PSR levels for different time frames.

My question is :
30m Time frame has Pivot / Support / Resistance level spanning the entire week. Value of these levels remain the same from the beginning of the week till the end (Mon - Friday).
How could we use this code to find the PSR levels for 30m Time frame as high / low / close keeps changing every day...What change needs to be done to find PSR levels for 30m Time frame

Appreciate your help!
Thanks.

```
get_PSR_Stats()=>
    pivot = (high[1] + low[1] + close[1]) / 3
    r1 = 2 * pivot - low[1]
    r2 = pivot + (high[1] - low[1])
    s1 = 2 * pivot - high[1]
    s2 = pivot - (high[1] - low[1])
    [pivot, r1, s1, r2, s2]

    [pivot, r1, s1, r2, s2] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5",get_PSR_Stats() , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    [pivot_w, r1_w, s1_w, r2_w, s2_w] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30",get_PSR_Stats() , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```